# Multiple iBeacons with Android and iBeacon-Library from Radius Networks

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am trying to monitoring a particular region with a specific **UUID**, **and any major/minor**.

So, I create a monitor with **a region having my UUID, and both major and minor being null**.

Now, I switch on a beacon, I get the Entry event. But after that, if I switch on another one, with the same UUID, it doesn't register an Entry event.

Same is with Exit events as well.

Anytime after this, while the two beacons are active, and then I turn off any one of them, I don't get an Exit event. I only get an Exit event when I turn off the other active beacon also.

Is this the expected behaviour? Or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour (or, it certainly is on iOS). When you're monitoring for a region with just a UUID, you'll only trigger an **entry** event when you enter a region covered by *any* beacon with that UUID. Adding another beacon to the same region won't give you another entry event, as you're ***already inside*** that region.

The same happens with your exit event. You turn off one region, but you're still located within a region covered by a beacon with the UUID that you're looking for.

However, if your two beacons were far apart so that their physical regions didn't overlap, then you should seen an exit as you leave one region and then an entry as you enter the next.

If you want to see the behaviour you're expecting when you turn on multiple beacons that are in the same physical location, you'd have to monitor each beacon's major / minor individually, so that the monitored regions are unique.

Comment: Can I start monitoring with a region without specifying any UUID, major and minor (i.e, setting all of them as null)?

Comment: I can't comment on the Android libraries, but on iOS you certainly have to specify the UUID you're interested in.

Comment: This answer is correct.  Yes, the Android iBeacon Library allows you to monitor or ange on a beacon region with all identifiers set to null.   The monitoring and Ranging sample code show exactly this: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html